# Counting number of certain characters between other characters

Tags: python-3.x

I have a csv file that has been stripped of most characters except the commas (,)

I would like to be able to count the number of commas that appear after the first ) "closing bracket" and the next non-comma character.

The data thus far presents as this

Job        : ## (323,3448,92s2,XxPt )
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

July01

so I want to count the long row of commas after the closing bracket on the Job line and stop counting when it hits the July01 line.

I have tried counting all commas etc but there are many more in the data file so I just want this specific row.

the csv was made from a pdf extract and used tabula and Pandas to create the file

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you want to count the commas on the line beginning with `Job` what does the `July01` line have to do with it?

Comment: Also, why is Python required? If you're on a Unix style OS (e.g., Linux) this can be done fairly simply using existing programs. For example, `sed -ne '/^Job /s/^.*) //p' x | wc -c`. The count will include the newline so subtract one.

Comment: Apologies, I'm trying to write a script in python. The number of commas (,) represents the number of days in the file....sometime this will be less/more. The idea was to use the commas to identify the number of days in the uploaded file. The above copy is a months data so 31 days, but I'd like to have the script identify an upload that only has 5 days or 20 days etc

Comment: Oh and I only want to count the commas after the closing bracket ')' not the ones before

Comment: I'd like the number of commas as a variable in python for other activities

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is still underspecified; i.e., ambiguous. But here is a solution that should get you moving in the right direction. This assumes the first line beginning with the string "Job :" is the one containing the data of interest.

```
import re

n_commas = 0
with open("data") as f:
    for l in f:
        if l.startswith("Job :"):
            match = re.match(r"^.*?\)[^,]?(,+)$", l)
            n_commas = len(match.group(1))
            break

print(n_commas)
```

Comment: The line starting with "Job :" has a few commas before the closing bracket at the end. Job : ## (323,3448,92s2,XxPt ) ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: The data in the brackets i.e. 323,3448,92s2,XxPt I don't want to count these commas just the ones after the closing bracket....

Comment: @MCla: Apparently you didn't try my solution. It works.

Comment: @MCla: I'm guessing you are not comfortable with regular expressions. This is a good opportunity for you to get more comfortable with their use. However, be aware that it is easy to use a regexp when that isn't the appropriate tool for the problem.